# TYPO3 svewap CleverReach with form extension and typoscript

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

i want use extension *svewap/CleverReach* with core *form* extension. I have typo3 7.6. I want create page for cleverreach in typoscript.

1. It is possible to use it in this way?
2. I should use finisher?
3. But finisher isn't avalible in my typo3 7.6 version.

Dokumentation page to my problem:
https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/cleverreach/UsersManual/Form/Index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to use the form examples with TYPO3 7. It requires the new form extension which comes with TYPO3 8.

Comment: So the only options is to use PowerMail in typo3 7? I'm not sure how to configere your extension for typo3. In documentation i see only two option - Form and powerMail.

Comment: Yes you can use the powermail extension instead. There is a small documentation how to use it with powermail. https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/cleverreach/UsersManual/Powermail/Index.html